# How to turn up the fan in the notebook to prevent overheating?

Tags: speedfan, fan

My Dell 15 inch Studio notebook recently is turning itself off, and I will touch the base of the notebook and usually it is fairly hot.

So there must be some design problem or after installing Windows 7, somehow the fan wasn't going high up in speed to cool down the system.   Is there any software or firmware that can make the fan go higher speed, so as to cool down the system earlier and better?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use the [Dell Inspiron/Latitude/Precision fan utility](http://www.diefer.de/i8kfan/). It was last updated in '07, but I believe it will work in W7 (don't take my word though).

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you are asking, however have you tried just using compressed air to clean out the fan? Lots of laptops suck in dirt / hair / lint that gunks up the tiny cooling fan on laptops.  Simply trying to turn up the speed won't always fix the problem if you have a 'blanket' on the heat-sink.

I've done this for a couple folks that had an overheating issue, and it usually solves the problem.

Comment: do you need to open up the laptop?  (because it may be hard to put back together afterwards)... or just buy some compress air can and blow into it?  (or maybe using vacuum cleaner to suck lint out of the fan outlet area?)  The Dell 15 Studio has the fan's outlet horizontally between the body and LCD, so it may be harder to maneuver.

Comment: Only in extreme cases do you need to open the laptop, try both tools (vacumm and compressed air can).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question actually lies in your tags.  SpeedFan is a utility that allows you to individually control the fans that are hooked up to your notebook (normally, this is usually only one fan).  Try take a crack at that.